# face detector with gender Male or Female

Tags: android, google-play-services, face-detection

```
private static final int REQUET_LOADIMAGE = 111;
private Button  btnDetect;
private ImageView image;
private Bitmap bitmap;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photogallery);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    btnDetect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDetect);
    btnDetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            detectFacesInImage();
        }
    });
   Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*"); // filter only image type files
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUET_LOADIMAGE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUET_LOADIMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void detectFacesInImage() {

    //Create a Paint object for drawing with
    Paint myRectPaint = new Paint();
    myRectPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    myRectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    myRectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    //Create a Canvas object for drawing on
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

    //Detect the Faces
    FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .build();
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
    SparseArray<Face> faces = faceDetector.detect(frame);

    if (faces.size() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "None face detected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        //Draw Rectangles on the Faces
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
            Face thisFace = faces.valueAt(i);
            float x1 = thisFace.getPosition().x;
            float y1 = thisFace.getPosition().y;
            float x2 = x1 + thisFace.getWidth();
            float y2 = y1 + thisFace.getHeight();


            tempCanvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(x1, y1, x2, y2), 2, 2, myRectPaint);
            faceDetector.release();
        }

        image.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
    }
}
}
```

I have successfully implemented face detection using google play-services-vision:9.4.0+' and also get the detected face by a simple program with the help of canvas.
I want to know the gender of the given photo on just onClicklistner.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I highly doubt you can do that, unless you use some sophisticated AI algorithms. Sometimes it's difficult even for a human to recognize a male from a female. And what about transgenders? You're trying to climb a mirror, I guess.

Comment: this looks like a few month task. You can't just write `face.getGender()` because it has no methods to do it. So you'll have to recognize it manually.

Comment: @Rotwang i have seen many app's which detect the gender with the accuracy of at least 90%

Comment: Name at least three. I sometimes fail to tell if one person is a male or a female at a first glance. And often fail to tell if a female is really such or if she's a trans.

Comment: @VladMatvienko can you elaborate,what you are trying to explain

Comment: @Rotwang -1-Age Recognization and many more these are the app

Comment: I mean that you can't get the gender of `Face` object. If you want to do it, you will have to implement your own algorithm for that, which would take me a few month to implement.

Comment: Then try to reverse-engineer that app.

Comment: @ Rotwang i failed in that :(

Comment: @VladMatvienko can you help me in this

Comment: which kind of help you expect? Do you want me to spend few months on developing the gender-detection algorithm?

Comment: @VladMatvienko no no .i don't want to kill your precious time .

Comment: you can tey using this API: http://www.faceplusplus.com/demo-detect/

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko I implemented face++ API .it shows error over network .

Comment: That means you implemented something wrong. And who knows what exactly...

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                                JSONArray parentArray = rst.getJSONArray("face");

                                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String gender = finalObject.getString("gender");
                                textview2.setText("" + gender);        its shows no value for gender

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this api: Gender Classification
    https://algorithmia.com/algorithms/deeplearning/GenderClassification

```
import com.algorithmia.*;
import com.algorithmia.algo.*;

String input = "{\n"
 + "    \"image\": \"data://deeplearning/example_data/m_ali.jpg\"\n"
 + "}";
AlgorithmiaClient client = Algorithmia.client("YOUR_API_KEY");
Algorithm algo = client.algo("algo://deeplearning/GenderClassification/1.0.1");
AlgoResponse result = algo.pipeJson(input);
System.out.println(result.asJsonString());
```

Json Result:

```
{
  "results": [
    [0.9948568344116211, "Male"],
    [0.0051431627944111815, "Female"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: actually i don't know but it's not for free . check pricing section there

Comment: in google vision api there is Facial Hair "moustache,beard" may help you

Comment: it's api so it support android for sure

Comment: can you me the example of Facial Hair in google vision ?

Comment: @farhan it's not fully free 
price and try section in this link
https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: anyother solutions ??

Comment: @farhan actually all solutions are apis with price no one will make a machine learning like this with free

Comment: .well thanks for the  answers I successfully implemented the API for gender detection .

Comment: i just successfully get the number of face count but when i want to show the result of gender and age it shows whole json result. i just want to put age and gender into the textview

Comment: @farhan check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: @amornew can i have your e-mail

Comment: @amornew you can mail me at mohdfarhantahir@gmail.com ,sir please help me

Comment: @farhan amorenew@gmail.com

Comment: just mail you .have a look